# Typescript: Can't instantiate object using object literals when a function exists in the class

Tags: angular, typescript2.0

I just started playing with Angular 2 and Typescript, and recently came across some behaviour I find quite strange.

My class looks like this:

```
export class Person{
  id: number;
  name: string;
  height: number;
  weight: number;

  calculateBmi() {
    return (weight/(height*height));
  }
}
```

When instantiating a new person using object literals, like this:

```
person: Person = {
    id: 1,
    name: "Jack Johnson",
    height: 180,
    weight: 70
  };
```

I get a (design time) error in Visual Studio 2017 saying:

> Type '{id: number, name: string, height: number, weight: number}' is not assignable to type 'Person'
>   Property 'calculateBmi' is missing in type '{id: number, name: string, height: number, weight: number}'

It also states that it

> Cannot convert type '{id: number, name: string, height: number, weight: number}' to type 'Person': Type 'Person' has non-optional property 'calculateBmi' which is not present in type '{id: number, name: string, height: number, weight: number}'.

So it seems that the transpiler regards 'calculateBmi' as a property, not a function.
The work around is of course to add a constructor and use that to instantiate the  class, but I'd like to learn if there is any way to solve this so I could still use object literals?

Thanx,
Jon

BTW.: I'm using Resharper 2017.x but I don't this this is what's causing the error message to appear.

Comment: You're telling TS that person is supposed to be of tye Person. The type Person declares a method calculateBmi. So, every time you have a Person instance, you're supposed to be able to call calculateBmi() on that instance. But your object literal doesn't have such a method. So you're trying to shoot yourself in the foot, and TypeScript prevents you from doing that. As you said, just call a constructor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your instantiation is wrong. Either call the constructor with new

```
person: Person = new Person()
```

Or create a complete object literal

```
person: Person = {
    id: 1,
    name: "Jack Johnson",
    height: 180,
    weight: 70,
    calculateBmi: function() {...}
  };
```

Comment: Thanks getjackx, but this means that I would have to define the function every time I'm instantiating the class.

This is far from optimal, but might be a trade off using object literals...?

Comment: Why would you want to use object literals anyway? If necessary you could write a constructor which accepts literals. Or you don't want the function in the class. You could write a controller or service if needed.

Comment: Well, I'm just trying to get to grips with the language.

Comment: I come from a C# background and was comparing this to instantiating classes using object initializers, but I guess they're quite different.
Thanks for the input getjackx!

Comment: @getjackx Why would you want to use object literals anyway? there might be a scenario where we are getting Person object from server over http call and need to map that json to Person type variable. In this scenario we can't access calculateBmi